# Making Commandline Parameters Optional in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am using ArgParse for giving commandline parameters in Python.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--quality", help="enter some quality limit")
args = parser.parse_args()
print "You gave quality = %s" % str(args.quality)
```

I saved this as `a.py` then ran this:

```
$ python a.py --quality 10
You gave quality = 10
```

I also want my code to run even if the commandline parameter is not provided.I want to make it optional.And if its provided,then it take a certain specific value which can be used further.

I have something like this in my code :

```
 if int(quality)==10:
```

So if I run without the parameter:

```
 $ python a.py
```

I get this error:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Erm... it is *already* optional. In fact the code you have written runs even without specifying the `--quality` option. You can specify a default value with the `default` keyword argument.

Comment: @Luigi That question is about making positional arguments optional. As pointed out by Bakuriu, arguments beginning with `-` are already optional.

Comment: I have added the error I am getting.

Comment: The default value is `None`. You need to either change the default or write code that can handle `None`.

Comment: I like to include a `print(args)` while developing with `argparse`.  In this case it would have clearly shown `quality=None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
parser.add_argument("--quality", 
                    type=int,
                    default=10,
                    help="enter some quality limit")
```

Specify the type as int and specify the default value you want. The problem you are encountering is because you haven't given the argument a default value (via the `default` keyword argument) so if it isn't specified on the command line it is defaulting to `None`, which int(quality) is choking on. Setting the `type` to `int` above avoids the need to do an `int()` cast at all.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the help document, [read that first](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("square", type=int, help="display a square of a given number")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbosity", type=int,
                    help="increase output verbosity")
args = parser.parse_args()
answer = args.square**2
if args.verbosity == 2:
    print "the square of {} equals {}".format(args.square, answer)
elif args.verbosity == 1:
    print "{}^2 == {}".format(args.square, answer)
else:
    print answer
```

Here's a solution to your question

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--quality", help="enter some quality limit")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.quality: #Optional parameter
    #act if it was provided
    print "You gave quality = %s" % str(args.quality)
else:
    #what to do if it wasn't provided
    print "You failed to provide a quantity"
```